# How to set a specific column to a int type with pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have this script for writing some csv files to a excel from a folder:

```
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas
import os

path = 'data/'
ordered_list = sorted(os.listdir(path), key = lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))


with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in ordered_list:
        pandas.read_csv(path + csv_file).to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file[:-4], encoding='utf-8')
```

Now my problem is that all columns (let's say G:H) are in string format (ex '400 or '10) with a ' before, I think they come as string because of csv converting them to strings, I need them to be int, how I can make G:H int?! I use python 3, thank you!

PS(this is a csv sample):

```
ANPIS,,,,,,,
AGENTIA JUDETEANA PENTRU PLATI SI INSPECTIE SOCIALA TIMIS,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
Macheta Comparativa CREDITORI - numai pentru Beneficiile a caror Evidenta se tine si in Contabilitate si in aplicatia SAFIR,,,,,,,
Situatie ANALITICA - NOMINAL la 30.06.2017,,,,,,,
1. ALOCATIA DE STAT PENTRU COPII,,,,,,,
Nr. Benef,Nume Prenume,CNP,Data Constituirii,Suma Contabilitate,Suma SAFIR,Differenta Suma,Explicatii daca exista diferente
1,2,3,4,5,6,7=5-6,8
1,CAZACU MIHAI,133121140,Aug 2016,84,84
2,NICOARA PETRU,143152638,"Aug 2014, Sept 2014",126,84
3,CERNEA NICOLAE DAN,143354723,Dec 2015,84,84
4,LUDWIG PETRU,144091376,Nov 2014,42,42
5,POPA REMUS,1440915363,Iun 2015,84,84
6,BOGDAN MARCEL,144154726,"Feb 2015, Apr 2015, Sept 2015, Oct 2015, Feb 2016",336,336
7,HENDRE AUGUSTIN,145054704,Feb 2015,42,42
8,COJOC VASILE,147050307,"Sept 2014, Oct 2014",84,84
9,RADULESCU VICTOR,147352628,"Sept 2014, Oct 2014, Nov 2014, Dec 2014",168,168
10,RADAU DUMITRU,148054764,"Feb 2017, Mar 2017",168,168
11,COVACIU PETRU,148054802,Iun 2016,84,84
12,BOT IOAN,14808634,"Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014, Nov 2014",168,168
```

^^ And the head is this one:

```
ANPIS,,,,,,,
AGENTIA JUDETEANA PENTRU PLATI SI INSPECTIE SOCIALA TIMIS,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
Macheta Comparativa CREDITORI - numai pentru Beneficiile a caror Evidenta se tine si in Contabilitate si in aplicatia SAFIR,,,,,,,
Situatie ANALITICA - NOMINAL la 30.06.2017,,,,,,,
1. ALOCATIA DE STAT PENTRU COPII,,,,,,,
Nr. Benef,Nume Prenume,CNP,Data Constituirii,Suma Contabilitate,Suma SAFIR,Differenta Suma,Explicatii daca exista diferente
1,2,3,4,5,6,7=5-6,8
```

Comment: Check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read each file twice - first header only with parameter `nrows` and then body with `skiprows`.

Then need write twice too.

Solution is a bit complicated, because pandas wrong parse data - not support MulttiIndex with `8` levels. If set no headers, data from header are joined with body and output is mess.

```
with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in ordered_list:
        df1 = pandas.read_csv(path + csv_file, nrows=8, header=None)
        df2 = pandas.read_csv(path + csv_file, skiprows=8, header=None)
        df1.to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file[:-4], encoding='utf-8', header=False)
        row = len(df1.index)
        df2.to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file[:-4], encoding='utf-8', startrow=row , startcol=0, header=False)
```

---

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for remove `'` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
cols = ['G','H']

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in ordered_list:
        df = pandas.read_csv(path + csv_file)
        df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("'")).astype(int)
        print (df.head())
        df.to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file[:-4], encoding='utf-8')
```

Another solution is use parameter `converters` with custom function:

```
cols = ['G','H']

def converter(x):
    return int(x.strip("'"))
#define each column
converters={x:converter for x in cols}

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in ordered_list:
        df = pandas.read_csv(path + csv_file, converters=converters)
        print (df.head())
        df.to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file[:-4], encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: For the first method I will get: IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible, and for the second nothing happens.

Comment: I check it again and test with my sample data. First solution was changed. Second solution working, but also was simplify. Can you check now? I add test `df` by `print (df.head())` - it return DataFrame with int columns `G,  H` ?

Comment: I think my header strings are messing up the format, when I deleted the headers on all csv s data was fine, can I skip somehow the header format so it wont affect?

Comment: I think you can use `header=None, skiprows=1)`  in read_csv if dont need read columns.

Comment: If I skiprows=6 the format will be proper without any conversions, but the problem is I wont see any of the headers, header= None won't have any effect.

Comment: I have no your real data, so not easy for me. ;) But skiprows means skip some lines from csv file and hader=None means dont read first line after skipped rows to columns names - instead it create default columns 0,1,2.... So I think both parameters are necessary.

Comment: I added a data sample in my original post so you can simulate, thank you! Notice the difference with and without header!

Comment: I think there is 8 rows in header - need `skiprows=8, header=None)`. Then in column 3 are multiple date per row. So what is desired output? only copy all data from 8th rows to csv?

Comment: I need all the data posted (with header also), but I need a proper int format for the cells E and F to be int (not with the '), header is making problems to the format thou!

Comment: Hmmm, I am a bit confused. After check your data I notice `"` is only with datetime like `"Aug 2014, Sept 2014"`. But it is necessary, because csv have separator `,` and data with dates contains `,` too - so was added `""`. So what column(s) is problematic? What is desired output in excel? Data without header? Can you explain more?

Comment: So, I will explain, if you edit and remove from my csv sample the header (first 8 rows) you will only have the body(where the names are starting from 1, CAZACU MIHAI...) the conversion to excel will work fine and all data will have a proper format, but if you do the conversion with the header (full sample) all the formats will get broken with that ( ' ) - could be that you excel is autoconverting but try a SUM function you will see it wont work and I need the column E and F as integers. But in my output excel I need the header also!!

Comment: I understand now. It is not easy, but I try find solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: Wow, good job sir, thank you so much! Lots of respect! Really appreciate it!